# Сделать аналог border-radius для svg circle?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, svg, css-animation

Есть вот такой прогресс бар с svg. Возможно как-то сделать чтобы, при значениях `< 100%` у окружности были закруглённые края? Как border-radius. 
Вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$('#percent').on('change', function(){
  var val = parseInt($(this).val());
  var $circle = $('#svg #bar');
  
  if (isNaN(val)) {
   val = 100; 
  }
  else{
    var r = $circle.attr('r');
    var c = Math.PI*(r*2);
   
    if (val < 0) { val = 0;}
    if (val > 100) { val = 100;}
    
    var pct = ((100-val)/100)*c;
    
    $circle.css({ strokeDashoffset: pct});
    
    $('#cont').attr('data-pct',val);
  }
});
```

```css
#svg circle {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s linear;
  stroke: #666;
  stroke-width: 1em;
}
#svg #bar {
  stroke: #FF9F1E;
}
#cont {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#cont:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1em black;
  content: attr(data-pct)"%";
  margin-top: -80px;
  margin-left: -80px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  line-height: 160px;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.5em black;
}

input {
  color: #000;
}


/* Make things perty */
html {  height: 100%;}
body { font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  background-color: #0d0d0d; color: #fff; height: 100%; padding-top: 2em; text-align: center;}
h1, h2{ margin: 0; text-transform: uppercase;text-shadow: 0 0 0.5em black;}
h2 { font-weight: 300}
input { border: 1px solid #666; background: #333; color: #fff; padding: 0.5em; box-shadow: none; outline: none !important; margin: 1em  auto; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cont" data-pct="100">
<svg id="svg" width="200" height="200" viewPort="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle r="90" cx="100" cy="100" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="565.48" stroke-dashoffset="0"></circle>
  <circle id="bar" r="90" cx="100" cy="100" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="565.48" stroke-dashoffset="0"></circle>
</svg>
</div>
<label for="percent">Type a percent!</label>
<input id="percent" name="percent">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для закругления краев сегмента, используйте атрибут [stroke-lineCap:round;](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-linecap)

```
  #svg #bar {
  stroke: #FF9F1E;
  stroke-lineCap:round;
```

```js
$('#percent').on('change', function(){
  var val = parseInt($(this).val());
  var $circle = $('#svg #bar');
  
  if (isNaN(val)) {
   val = 100; 
  }
  else{
    var r = $circle.attr('r');
    var c = Math.PI*(r*2);
   
    if (val < 0) { val = 0;}
    if (val > 100) { val = 100;}
    
    var pct = ((100-val)/100)*c;
    
    $circle.css({ strokeDashoffset: pct});
    
    $('#cont').attr('data-pct',val);
  }
});
```

```css
#svg circle {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s linear;
  stroke: #666;
  stroke-width: 1em;
}
#svg #bar {
  stroke: #FF9F1E;
   stroke-lineCap:round;

}
#cont {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#cont:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1em black;
  content: attr(data-pct)"%";
  margin-top: -80px;
  margin-left: -80px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  line-height: 160px;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.5em black;
}

input {
  color: #000;
}


/* Make things perty */
html {  height: 100%;}
body { font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  background-color: #0d0d0d; color: #fff; height: 100%; padding-top: 2em; text-align: center;}
h1, h2{ margin: 0; text-transform: uppercase;text-shadow: 0 0 0.5em black;}
h2 { font-weight: 300}
input { border: 1px solid #666; background: #333; color: #fff; padding: 0.5em; box-shadow: none; outline: none !important; margin: 1em  auto; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cont" data-pct="100">
<svg id="svg" width="200" height="200" viewPort="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle r="90" cx="100" cy="100" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="565.48" stroke-dashoffset="0"></circle>
  <circle id="bar" r="90" cx="100" cy="100" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="565.48" stroke-dashoffset="0"></circle>
</svg>
</div>
<label for="percent">Type a percent!</label>
<input id="percent" name="percent">
```